# How to send commands and redirect the output with interactive programs in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i want to write a script in bash that can connect to a port and save the output to a file. But I have a few problems with this.

First one: how do i restore the output?

For example I try to connect to an port 21 with "ftp 127.0.0.1"

It will print the ftp banner ask for user/pass etc. What I want to do is just saving the Banner and exit. Simply writing exit doesn't work. Neither does quit and then exit. It will just stay like it is and won't show stdout. I have to manually type quit or with the "nc" command just ctrl-c that i get my output back.

So how do i send commands to an interactive program and how do i restore stdout?

I'm looking forward to an answer

Sheez

Comment: Show some code, explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Take a look at this articles: [1](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2006/05/23/bash-socket-programming-with-devtcp-2/) [2](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bashs-built-devtcp-file-tcpip)

Comment: You might want to use "expect"

Comment: http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm

Comment: `nc 127.0.0.1 21 </dev/null >file`